# Как сделать обратную связь Telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Ситуация такая, мне нужен бот обратной связи который будет вызываться только после оплаты с
помощью

> @bot.message_handler(content_types=['successful_payment'])

Но при попытке запустить комманду /close бот принимает только одно сообщение, а дальше происходит ошибка, что делать?

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['successful_payment']) 
        global help_user_id
        help_user_id = m.chat.id
        bot.send_message(TO_CHAT_ID, f'<b>✅У тебя новый клиент!</b>\nНикнейм: @{m.from_user.username}', parse_mode="html")
        msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, '‍Соеденил вас с продавцом. Вскоре вы получите ответ')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, helpBot)
    
    @bot.message_handler(content_types= ["text", "audio", "photo", "voice"]) def handle_text(m):
            # здесь если чат id равен id чата поддержки, то отправить сообщение пользователю который задал вопрос
        if int(m.chat.id) == int(TO_CHAT_ID):
            bot.send_message(help_user_id, m.text)
        else:
            bot.send_message(TO_CHAT_ID, f'Свяжись с клиентом\nНик: @{m.from_user.username}')
            bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Ошибка! Ожидайте ответа администрации', parse_mode='html')
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['close']) def end(m): 
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Оставить отзыв', callback_data='review')
                btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Меню', callback_data='back1')
                markup.row(btn1, btn2)
                bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Спасибо за покупку! \nВ скором времени вам выдадут товар\nИли свяжутся с вами в случае ошибки!', reply_markup=markup)
```